# Call additional method on DB::update or DB::delete (laravel, eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in the process of trying to create a logging interface for our application. I need to track when a change happens in the database through the application. So when someone updates a field I need to insert a row into the log with the table, columns original value, columns new value, timestamp, and user that made change. To me the logical way of doing this is to tie into the DB class in laravel so everytime it's called and an update / delete method is used it runs my new method of getting the needed info and inserting it in the log.

I need it to work at the DB level I believe as it needs to happen for updates / deletes called from DB or eloquent.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon searching and trial and error I accomplished my goal the following way.

I created an Event listener that I for organizational purposes placed in /app/events/database.php

With the following

```
<?php
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $bindings, $time, $name)
{
  // Code to log query goes here  
});
```

I then placed in my /app/start/global.php the following line

```
include(app_path().'/events/database.php');
```

This now captures all requests to query the database using either DB, or Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent provides you with some nice events, they're even in the docs ! Who knew you can find so much in there.
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events

Comment: The problem is there are instances were Eloquent isn't used for more complex queries and using those events only capture ones issued by eloquent and not DB directly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to attach something onto the DB layer, have you considered using Model Observers (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers) to watch all update and delete events and put your logic in that observer?

Comment: The problem is there are instances were Eloquent isn't used for more complex queries and using those events only capture ones issued by eloquent and not DB directly.